# creating simple stopwatch - javaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I try to avoid asking for help and do as much as I can by myself. But I half been working on this for far too long. I don't even understand what is wrong. oh and when I try to test it my GUI freezes

I have to make a basic stop watch: start, stop, resume, and reset. and yet i can't do it. Please if you would also comment or explain your code, because I feel clueless. (some of my comments are past code I thought would work but didn't)

```
package gameclock;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class GameClock extends Application {


public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    HBox pane = new HBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 100);


    Button start = new Button("Start");
    Button stop = new Button("Stop");
    Button resume = new Button("Resume");
    Button reset = new Button("Reset");
    final TextField display = new TextField("0");
    display.setEditable(false);

    boolean onOff = false;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
    Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(df.format(calobj.getTime()));

    start.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
    {
        int time = Integer.parseInt(display.getText());
        /*
        Timer t = new Timer();

        final int time1 = 1;
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                time = time1 + 1;
            }
        },0,0);

        display.setText(String.valueOf(time1));
        */

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); //divide by 1000 cause a millisecond is 1000 of a second
        while (!onOff)
        {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp > 1000)
            {
                time++;
                display.setText(String.valueOf(time)); 
            }
        }

        String time2String = Long.toString(timestamp);

    });
    stop.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
    {
        if(onOff == false)
            onOff(true);

    });
    resume.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> 
    {
       onOff(true); 

    });


    pane.getChildren().addAll(start, display, resume, stop, reset);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Stop Watch");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private void onOff(boolean b) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're blocking the application thread by adding the loop directly to the event handler. This results in the UI not being updated and no further events being handled.

Better use a [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html):

```
AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
    private long timestamp;
    private long time = 0;
    private long fraction = 0;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // current time adjusted by remaining time from last run
        timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - fraction;
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        // save leftover time not handled with the last update
        fraction = System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (timestamp + 1000 <= newTime) {
            long deltaT = (newTime - timestamp) / 1000;
            time += deltaT;
            timestamp += 1000 * deltaT;
            display.setText(Long.toString(time));
        }
    }
};
```

This will run the `handle` method on the application thread every frame.

You can use `start()` and `stop()` to start and stop the stopwatch.

Answer (score 0):

I can recognize an infinite loop with the best of them:

```
    while (!onOff)
    {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp > 1000)
        {
            time++;
            display.setText(String.valueOf(time)); 
        }
    }
```

I don't know much about JavaFX as I do Java/Android, but there's nothing that's going to toggle `onOff` from false to true within that loop.  Even if you have another button callback to toggle `onOff` to true, it won't get called because your UI thread is stuck in the loop above for the start button action.

Update:

Now that I see what you are trying to do: Update a text value with the current time, what you want to be using is the notion of a *timer*.  A timer is UI concept in which you get called back in the future while still allowing your UI to be responsive.  A quick google of "JavaFX timer" reveals lots of hits on how to do this.

Comment: I know that the loop is endless. I designed it that way. I want it to be so that when the stop button is pressed it takes it out of the loop.

Comment: Here's the problem.  Your button callbacks happen on the the main thread of your application - issued by a dispatch event handler that runs in a loop at the bottom of your callstack.  If your button event handler has not returned, other event handlers won't be able to run.  Hence, your UI thread freezes while in an infinite loop and becomes unresponsive.  What you want to do is see my updated answer regarding a UI timer.  Just do an internet seach for "Java timer" or "JavaFX timer".  You likely just need a timer event to fire every 1 second do you can update the text on the screen.